# WPF Style/Themes: placeholder

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, themes

I have a WPF project which have 2 Themes, Dark and Light.
The themes are placed In a separate folders located in my debug.

**DarkTheme.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="Handle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF323232" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Label" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFC8C8C8" />
</Style>
```

**LightTheme.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="Handle" TargetType="Grid">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFAFAFA" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="Label" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF323232" />
</Style>
```

**I then apply the Theme to a Label as a DynamicResource**

```
<Label Content="TestLabel" Style="{DynamicResource Label}" Foreground="#FF323232"/>
```

**And This Is How I Load Them**

```
private void ThemeChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (combo.SelectedIndex == -1) return;

        foreach (var command in Directory.GetFiles(((ThemeData)combo.SelectedValue).ThemePath).Where(x => x.EndsWith(".xaml")))
        {
            var stream = new FileStream(command, FileMode.Open);

            foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(stream))
            {
                Application.Current.Resources[dictionaryEntry.Key] = dictionaryEntry.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

### Problem

The labels foreground wont change when changing theme (runtime), unless I leave the Foreground as null. But I can't leave everything blank in the design (since I cant work with a blank screen)

So how do I make the theme override the style? Or maybe I can make a placeholder style?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are doing to load the theme resources, but what you need to do is unload the previous theme (remove it from the application resources) then load the new theme. If you have them both loaded into the resources at the same time, there is no way for controls to determine which one to apply.

Edit:
Since you are merging the keys into the application resources and then replacing them when the theme changes (and that is not working), then changing the value of an existing resource must not be enough to trigger an update.

In my own personal WPF theme library, when I load a theme, I take the dictionary generated by the theme and add it to the application's Resources.MergedDictionaries collection. I also keep a reference to the dictionary so that when I later unload the theme, I can remove it from the merged dictionaries collection. Doing it this way ensures that all of the theme resources are completely unloaded. You may want to consider doing something similar.

P.S. You are creating a file stream and never closing it. That will result in that file being inaccessible until the application is closed. You should wrap that block of code in a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).